# Copy Data from one table to another

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables in SQL Server as follows which are related through the FK SOPGroupsID:-

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SOPGroups](
    [SOPGroupsID]       smallint NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    [SOP_Group]         varchar(200) NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
   PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (SOPGroupsID));
   GO

   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SOPTitle](
     [SOPGroupsID]  smallint DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL,
     [SOPTitleID]   smallint NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1), 
     [SOP_Title]    varchar(300) NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
     PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (SOPTitleID));
     GO
   --add relationship between tables SOPGroups and SOPTitle  
   ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SOPTitle] ADD CONSTRAINT [R1] FOREIGN KEY(SOPGroupsID) 
   REFERENCES [dbo].[SOPGroups] (SOPGroupsID) 
   ON UPDATE Cascade 
   ON DELETE Set default;
   GO
```

I am importing data from an excel file which the first step is import the excel file into a temporary table in SQL server and then import the data into the tables above removing duplicate entries. I insert the SOP Group Data as follows into table SOPGroups:-

```
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[SOPGroups] (SOP_Group)
        SELECT DISTINCT SOP_Group FROM [dbo].['Onthology Return$'] t
        WHERE NOT EXISTS
            (SELECT SOP_Group FROM [dbo].[SOPGroups] x WHERE x.SOP_Group = t.SOP_Group)
```

My problem is how to insert into table [SOPTitle] and get the SOPGroupID from table SOPGroups based on the SOP_Group name matched to the distinct SOP_Title  from the temporary table 'Onthology Return$'.

```
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[SOPTitle] (SOPGroupsID, SOP_Title) 
    SELECT DISTINCT SOP_Group, SOP_Title FROM [dbo].['Onthology Return$'] t
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the group id using a join between the group names.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[SOPTitle] (SOPGroupsID, SOP_Title) 
SELECT DISTINCT g.SOPGroupsID, t.SOP_Title 
FROM [dbo].['Onthology Return$'] t 
INNER JOIN [dbo].[SOPGroups] g ON t.SOP_Group = g.SOP_Group
```

Answer (score 0):

As new SOP_Group values were inserted into SOPGroups we can use an `INNER JOIN` on SOP_Group between this table and the imported table. This will return all the SOP_Titles relating to the inserted SOP_Groups and we take their respective SOPGroupIDs from the SOPGroups table.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[SOPTitle] (SOPGroupsID, SOP_Title) 
SELECT DISTINCT g.SOPGroupsID, t.SOP_Title 
FROM [dbo].['Onthology Return$'] t 
INNER JOIN [dbo].[SOPGroups] g ON t.SOP_Group = g.SOP_Group
```

As a caveat, the `SELECT DISTINCT` statement is working differently on the second insert, as it allows multiple SOP_Title values to be inserted for each SOP_Group.